# Where does magento do the redirect to configured base_url?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, redirect, base-url

I'm trying to log calls to my magento installation through the old domain. I cannot figure out where the redirect to the configured new domain takes place.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, got it by myself ;-)

The magic is hidden in **`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php`**:

```
class Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front extends Varien_Object
{

    // ...


    /**
     * Auto-redirect to base url (without SID) if the requested url doesn't match it.
     * By default this feature is enabled in configuration.
     *
     * @param Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request
     */
    protected function _checkBaseUrl($request)
    {
        if (!Mage::isInstalled() || $request->getPost() || strtolower($request->getMethod()) == 'post') {
            return;
        }

        $redirectCode = (int)Mage::getStoreConfig('web/url/redirect_to_base');
        if (!$redirectCode) {
            return;
        } elseif ($redirectCode != 301) {
            $redirectCode = 302;
        }

        if ($this->_isAdminFrontNameMatched($request)) {
            return;
        }

        $baseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(
            Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB,
            Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()
        );
        if (!$baseUrl) {
            return;
        }

        $uri = @parse_url($baseUrl);
        $requestUri = $request->getRequestUri() ? $request->getRequestUri() : '/';
        if (isset($uri['scheme']) && $uri['scheme'] != $request->getScheme()
            || isset($uri['host']) && $uri['host'] != $request->getHttpHost()
            || isset($uri['path']) && strpos($requestUri, $uri['path']) === false
        ) {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect($baseUrl, $redirectCode)
                ->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
    }

    // ...

}
```